# Prove triangle inequality for inner product $\langle a,c\rangle \leq \langle a,b\rangle + \langle b,c\rangle $

Tags: geometry, triangle-inequality

> For all $a,b,c$ which are vectors, determine whether $\langle a,c\rangle \leq \langle a,b\rangle + \langle b,c\rangle $ is true or false.

I have considered Cauchy-Schwartz inequality,
but there is a $||b||^2$ left on right hand side, I cannot prove it after that, how can I eliminate $||b||^2$ to make the $\langle a,c\rangle \leq \langle a,b\rangle + \langle b,c\rangle $ is true?

Comment: Take $a=c\neq \mathbf{0}$ and $b=\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: Let $a$ and $c$ be any non-zero, non-orthogonal vectors and choose $b$ to be orthogonal to both of them.

Comment: Thank you guys!

Comment: But the right hand side is all zero isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's the point...!

Comment: Ohh i see, so this statement is false!